# Answer getting -10 for no reason

Tags: support, bug

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/458492/489896) got accepted 7 days ago but I received a reputation notification today saying that it got -10 reputation.
When I looked in the post's [timeline](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/458492/timeline), it says nothing about this (no noticed, no downvote...9).

Why is this?
Is this a bug or something? How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The timeline doesn't show any information about votes.

You can see details about reputation changes on https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/489896/thinkr?tab=reputation&sort=post. For the post in question it says

[image]

So the post was upvoted before (the +25 on April 13th), but the upvote was removed by whoever voted for it in the first place.